# Can formatting a Spock Specification be controlled in Eclipse/STS?

Tags: eclipse, code-formatting, spock

Eclipse is formatting my Spock tests like this:

```
def "Trivial example"() {
    setup:
    def consoleMock = Mock(TestConsole) {
        1 * readLine('provide input 1: ') >> 'response 1'
        1 * readLine('provide input 2: ') >> 'response 2'
        1 * readLine('provide input 3: ') >> 'response 3'
    }
    processor.inputMethods.cons = consoleMock
    when:
    def testResult1 = processor.getInput(1, 'provide input 1: ')
    def testResult2 = processor.getInput(2, 'provide input 2: ')
    def testResult3 = processor.getInput(3, 'provide input 3: ')
    then:
    testResult3 == 'response 3'
    noExceptionThrown()
}
```

I would like to have them formatted like this:

```
def "Trivial example"() {
    setup:
        def consoleMock = Mock(TestConsole) {
            1 * readLine('provide input 1: ') >> 'response 1'
            1 * readLine('provide input 2: ') >> 'response 2'
            1 * readLine('provide input 3: ') >> 'response 3'
        }
        processor.inputMethods.cons = consoleMock
    when:
        def testResult1 = processor.getInput(1, 'provide input 1: ')
        def testResult2 = processor.getInput(2, 'provide input 2: ')
        def testResult3 = processor.getInput(3, 'provide input 3: ')
    then:
        testResult3 == 'response 3'
        noExceptionThrown()
}
```

I can not get the formatter to do so.  The only way I have found is to format it correctly by hand and then insert @formmatter:off/@formatter:on tags.  Without the tags Eclipse reformats to the first version [I need to have formatting on at Save time for other reasons.]  Not only is this ugly, it doesn't scale very well across hundreds of tests!  Is a better way possible?

Finally, sorry for asking such a non-technical question, but as can be seen above, the formatting really does affect readability and I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is looking to solve this formatting issue, I installed the Spock Eclipse Plugin from here:

```
http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spock-plugin#.UtWI_GTF3VQ
```

and was subsequently all set formatting-wise!